# android asynctask compile issues

Tags: java, android, multithreading, compiler-errors, android-asynctask

I'm trying to write an app that accesses a webpage my friend created as a joke where users can give "medals" to one another for stupid things. an example is the owner of the site gave another friend whom i shall call bob a medal called "password genius" with the description "Forgot his MIT admissions password and is just bad at passwords in general.". the medals are retrieved in JSON format, and the above example would be 
`[...other medals....,{"medalid":"21","uid":"bob","title":"Password Genius","description":"Forgot his MIT admissions password and is just bad at passwords in general.","givenby":"fred"}, ...other medals....]`
. I want to retrieve these using an AsyncTask in my app, but i get the weirdest compiler errors. my code is, in a nutshell,

```
public class MedalMania extends activity
{
    public static final String TAG = "[MedalMania]";
    public void lookupButtonPressed(View view)
    {
        (new GetMedalsTask()).execute(((EditText)R.findViewById(R.id.name_box))getText().toString());
    }
    private class GetMedalsTask extends AsyncTask<String, void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "This will print to console");
            return "i dont need to type my real code, even this simplified form wont work";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String json)
        {
            Log.v(TAG, json);//This wont print to console
        }
    }
}
```

if I try to do that, I get

```
[javac] Compiling 4 source files to /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/bin/classes
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:59: illegal start of type
[javac]     private class GetMedalsTask extends AsyncTask<String, void, String>
[javac]                                                           ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:59: '{' expected
[javac]     private class GetMedalsTask extends AsyncTask<String, void, String>
[javac]                                                               ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:59: <identifier> expected
[javac]     private class GetMedalsTask extends AsyncTask<String, void, String>
[javac]                                                                       ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:62: ';' expected
[javac]         protected String doInBackground(String... params)
[javac]                                        ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:62: not a statement
[javac]         protected String doInBackground(String... params)
[javac]                                         ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:62: ';' expected
[javac]         protected String doInBackground(String... params)
[javac]                                               ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:62: not a statement
[javac]         protected String doInBackground(String... params)
[javac]                                                   ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:62: ';' expected
[javac]         protected String doInBackground(String... params)
[javac]                                                         ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:76: illegal start of type
[javac]         protected void onPostExecute(String json)
[javac]                   ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:76: ';' expected
[javac]         protected void onPostExecute(String json)
[javac]                       ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:76: ')' expected
[javac]         protected void onPostExecute(String json)
[javac]                                            ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:76: not a statement
[javac]         protected void onPostExecute(String json)
[javac]                                     ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:76: ';' expected
[javac]         protected void onPostExecute(String json)
[javac]                                                 ^
[javac] /home/alex/droid_apps/MedalMania/src/com/alex/medalmania/MedalMania.java:81: reached end of file while parsing
[javac] }
[javac]  ^
[javac] 14 errors
```

however, if I replace

```
private class GetMedalsTask extends AsyncTask<String, void, String>
```

with

```
private class GetMedalsTask extends AsyncTask//<String, void, String>
```

it will compile, but only the Log.v(TAG, "this will print to console"); actually prints, not the `Log.v(TAG, json)`;. I have looked up other tutorials, and they look pretty much identical. i cant figure out for the life of me. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
       AsyncTask<String, void, String>
```

should be

```
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> // V is capital
```

Also

```
      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, json);//This wont print to console
    }
```

shoudl be

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json)
    {
       super.onPostExecute(json);
        Log.v(TAG, json);//This wont print to console
    }
```

The result of `doInBackground` computation is a paramter to `onPostExecute`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Check the topic under AsyncTask generic types.

Also check the topic  under the section  The 4 steps.

Comment: onPostExecute still wont print anything

Comment: @fizyplankton where is your `onCreate` of your activtiy?

Comment: Nevermind yes it does. instead of doInBackground returning that test string, I thought I had it printing. So when I saw onPostExecute printing what doInBackground fed it, I though it was doInBackground printing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I left it out. And the imports. And a bunch of other stuff. I didn't think it was relevant

Comment: @fizyplankton the result of `doInbackground` computation is a parameter to `onPostExecute`. see the asynctask docs

Comment: @fizyplankton http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. check this under the topic The 4 steps.

Comment: I thought i had my old code in there. I just got confused. My old code printed a bunch of verbose stuff. It works now

Answer (score 1):

`void` is not a reference type..

You need to use [Void](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) which is a reference type

Comment: .....That's embarrassing lol. And now it compiles, but only the first Log.v() works. Thanks for the speedy response